# problem in printing out the character in console

Tags: c++, printing

In my code I did this

```
int y=strcmp(s,s1);//before this I converted all the uppercase of the string input as lower case.

if(y==0)
{

    cout<<"0"<<endl;
}
else if(y >= 1)
{
    cout<<"1"<<endl;
}
else if(y<1)
{
    cout<<"-1"<<endl;//problem was here
}
```

so i took `aaaa` and `aaaA` as input and expected `0` as output . But it gave me `-1` as output.
But in my code when I wrote this:

```
int y=strcmp(s,s1);

if(y==0)
{

    cout<<0<<endl;
}
else if(y >= 1)
{
    cout<<1<<endl;
}
else if(y<1)
{
    cout<<-1<<endl;
}
```

It gave me the right answer.
My question why this happened?

Comment: The two pieces of code you show are identical.

Comment: you must have changed something else!

Comment: I don't know much about C++, but it probably has to do with the output you're giving. `"0"` means to output a string with the content `0`, but output `0` as-is seems more like an exit code, which is not written to the console but considered an error code.

Comment: Does it still happen with the two code variants, if you try again? Can you please provide the examples with setting s and s1 inside program?

Answer (score 0):

you removed " " in the cout. Can you show the error code you're getting in the first round?